# Uploading Images using paperclip in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to upload an image in my Rails Application. However, I am unable to do so. I am relatively new to rails and I need some help here.

I have a "Picture" Model shown here -

```
 class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

     attr_accessible :photo, :tag

     has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",
     :large => "1000x1000>",     :thumb => "100x100>" }

 end
```

I have a "Pictures" Controller shown here -

```
 class PicturesController < ApplicationController

    def new
            @picture = Picture.new
    end

    def create
            @picture = Picture.create( params[:picture] )
            if @picture.save
                    flash.now[:success] = "Image Uploaded"
                    redirect_to @picture
            else
                    render 'new'
            end
    end

    def index
    end

    def show
            @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
            send_data @picture.photo, :type => 'image/png', :disposition => 'inline'
    end

    def imageshow
    end

 end
```

Lastly, These are my "new" and "show" views:

"new.html.erb"

```
 <h1>Upload an Image</h1>
 <div>
    <%= form_for(@picture, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
       <%= f.file_field :photo %>
       <%= f.label :tag %>
       <%= f.text_field :tag %>
       <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

"show.html.erb"

```
 <h1>Displaying Uploaded Image</h1>
 <div>
     <%= image_tag @picture.photo.url %>
     <%= image_tag @picture.photo.url(:large) %>
 </div>
```

*I am able to reach the Upload page (ie, new.html.erb in Pictures Controller). However, when I upload an image I get the following error:*

**"This image "http://10.102.119.20:3000/pictures/12" cannot be displayed because it contains errors"**

My queries are:

1. Where does an image get uploaded on the server?
2. Is there any configuration that needs to be done?
3. Is there any other issue with my code?

Thanks in advance for any help..!!

Comment: I know, as at when last I used paperclip, the image gets uploaded to the `public` directory

Comment: Yasky, that is true. I somehow found out that by default, the images get uploaded to /public directory. To be precise, /root/rails_project/sample_app/public/system/pictures/photos.. However, I am not able to show the images using show method in picture controller. You can see what I am using in the show method above. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Bates discusses [Paperclip in his Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip). Check it out. It helped me get started.